# How to asynchronously run JBoss server application from Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, server, jboss

In my java application, I need to run a Jboss server with the file `standalone.bat`.

I tried `ProcessBuilder`, and though it did start the server, my application is blocked waiting for the server to go down

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "api/project/liststart", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HttpEntity<Boolean> postListServer(@RequestBody ListStart modules) throws Throwable {

        String cmd = "";
        Boolean response = false;

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();

        String path = "C:\\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\\bin\\";
        String command = standelone.bat+ " >sometext.txt"  ;

        processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
        processBuilder.directory(new File(path));

        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String ligne;
        while ((ligne = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(ligne);
        }


        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("\nExited with error code : " + exitCode);



        String F = path + "\\SomeFile.txt";
        System.out.println("------------------------file: " + F);
        File file = new File(F);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        //now read the file line by line...
        int lineNum = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            lineNum++;
            if (line.contains("Started server")) {
                response = true;
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------" + response.toString());

            }
        }

        ResponseEntity responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        return responseEntity;
    }


}
```

I expect the method above to return `true` value, but it's being blocked before a value can be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like scanner.hasNextLine() can't get out from while cycle, so try like this :

```
     while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                lineNum++;
                if (line.contains("Started server")) {
                    response = true;
                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------" + response.toString());

     return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
                } else {
     return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
            }
```

Comment: i added a break; in while cycle

Comment: Are you sure that execution go into this statement  `if (line.contains("Started server"))` ?